# AutoCompleteTextView no funciona al dar espacio

Tags: android, webservice, programación-móvil

Tengo un TextAutoCompleteView, el cual trae los datos de un WebServices y al cargar el adaptador para hacer las sugerencias, todo funciona perfectamente.

**El problema lo tengo a la hora de incluir un espacio, ya que me elimina todas las posibilidades.**

Ejemplo si pongo San Juan

Solo tomar el valor "San"  al darle espacio pierdo todas las sugerencias

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,listaCargada1);
    txtbuscar.setThreshold(1);
    txtbuscar.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que funcione con espacios debes modificar el Adapter, en este caso **crear un CustomAdapter.**

Agrego un [ejemplo](http://makovkastar.github.io/blog/2014/04/12/android-autocompletetextview-with-suggestions-from-a-web-service/) (creado por [Alex Melnykov](http://makovkastar.github.io/) ).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    public class BookAutoCompleteAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    private static final int MAX_RESULTS = 10;
    private Context mContext;
    private List<Book> resultList = new ArrayList<Book>();

    public BookAutoCompleteAdapter(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return resultList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Book getItem(int index) {
        return resultList.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_2line, parent, false);
        }
        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1)).setText(getItem(position).getTitle());
        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text2)).setText(getItem(position).getAuthor());
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                if (constraint != null) {
                    List<Books> books = findBooks(mContext, constraint.toString());

                    // Assign the data to the FilterResults
                    filterResults.values = books;
                    filterResults.count = books.size();
                }
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    resultList = (List<Books>) results.values;
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }};
        return filter;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a search result for the given book title.
     */
    private List<Book> findBooks(Context context, String bookTitle) {
        // GoogleBooksProtocol is a wrapper for the Google Books API
        GoogleBooksProtocol protocol = new GoogleBooksProtocol(context, MAX_RESULTS);
        return protocol.findBooks(bookTitle);
    }
}
```

Comment: Excelente, me guié con el ejemplo y quedo Perfecto.

Gracias.

Comment: @AndreyC1995 perfecto Andrey!!! saludos!